Can an Orthodox Jew attend a Christmas party?
Can an Orthodox Jew attend a Christmas party? Many Jewish people have Christian friends, and those that have undergone a conversion to Judaism typically also have Christian friends (as well relationships with the family that they grew up with). Is there anything that would make this forbidden?

Exodus 34:15 was in the Torah reading just this past Saturday morning

Wandering under the mistletoe could lead to mixed dancing.

@ClintEastwood Some might say that mixed dancing could lead to wandering under the mistletoe.

@DoubleAA “The inhabitants of the land” clearly refers to the Canaanites. Can we be sure that a.) this prohibition extends to outside the Land of Israel, and to other peoples, and b.) that Christmas has the same status as an idolatrous festival?

@ezra The Talmud does assume both those things

R. Ari Wasserman has a section in his book Making it work dedicated to the question of attending non-Jewish social gatherings and holiday parties.
He identifies several issues:

A Torah prohibition of eating at a non-Jewish wedding (see YD 152:1)
Concerns of idolatry
Concerns that it would lead to intermarriage
Having to balance the above concerns with the need to maintain cordial relations with non-Jews (eivah)

Regarding office parties specifically, he brings multiple opinions, from those strictly forbidding them (e.g., when no legitimate need, parties before non-Jewish holidays with food and alcohol served, or mixed dancing) to certain opinions permitting them (e.g., where non-attendance might bring significant repercussions and parties are professional rather than for enjoyment).
R. Doniel Neustadt (here) brings the following:

It depends on the type of party the company is having. Many times, a
company’s holiday party has nothing to do with the celebration of the
holiday; rather it is an employee appreciation party that happens to
take place during the holiday season. There is no halachic objection
to attending such a party. But if the intention of the party is to
celebrate the actual non-Jewish holiday, it would be forbidden for a
Jew to attend.
However, even if the party is not intended to celebrate a non-Jewish
holiday, non-Jewish office parties are hardly the place for an
observant Jew to be. The mode of dress, the type of language and the
loose behavior at such affairs is completely alien and contrary to
everything that Yiddishkeit stands for. It is clear, therefore, that
if for business reasons one must attend such a party, he or she must
do so only when there is no other choice, and even then, he or she
must come and go as quickly as possible. Lingering in such an
environment can lead to serious transgression of many Torah laws.

For further sources see here and there.

The main issue may possibly be the Gemara (Avodah Zarah 8a) that states that "Jews in the Diaspora worship idolatry in purity". What does this mean? When a Gentile makes a personal celebration (like a wedding for their child), he invites Jews to the party and they attend. Even though they eat their own kosher food, the Torah considers it as if they are eating idolatrous sacrifices from the host. It says, “Lest you make a covenant with the inhabitants of the land, and they prostitute themselves to their gods and sacrifice to their gods, and one of them invites you and you eat of his sacrifice” (Ex. 34:15). The end of the verse implies that you may not accept an invitation from an idolater and, if you do, it is as if you are eating from his idolatrous sacrifice.
This being said- it is quite possible that these aren’t really "religious" celebrations. Most large companies nowadays try to accommodate people of all religions and do not have explicitly religious celebrations. These “holiday” parties and are entirely secular. If something even remotely religious happens, like singing Christmas carols or someone entering dressed as Santa Claus, I would possibly leave (Although I’m not convinced that either of the two examples I mentioned are actually religious). But really we are just talking about a neutral holiday party.
Gentiles today do not worship idolatry and, even if they do, they do not thank their god that a Jew who works in their legal department attended a mandatory business party.
People may get very offended if Jews as a group, or even religious Jews as a group, refuse to go to the company’s holiday party. The company spends a lot of money on what they consider to be a morale booster and if you refuse to participate, especially after they make certain that there is nothing religiously offensive and glatt kosher food is available, you are undermining company morale and offending executives.
sources for more details:
Shulchan Arukh (Yoreh De’ah 152:1)- see discussions of shach and Taz of biblical or rabbinic.
Rav Menasheh Klein (Mishneh Halakhos 7:118)  rules like Taz (not allowed)
Levush explicitly rules that eivah (offending) overrides the prohibition against attending a Gentile party (to which the Taz objects)
Rav Moshe Feinstein (Iggeros Moshe, Yoreh De’ah 2:117) seems to rule like Shach, allowing it in cases of eivah.

Wouldn't it make a difference in the work place if the employer is billing the event as a "holiday party" vs a "Christmas party"? I would never go to a work event that called itself a Christmas party. I would consider going to a holiday party but then I would judge how "Christmasy" it came accross and base my decision to attend in future years on that.

I believe the question was one of Halacha. You are making a valid point about sensitivity.

"singing Christmas carols or someone entering dressed as Santa Claus... not convinced they're actually religious" - Perspective from a random Christian, FWIW: singing Christmas carols may not really be religious anymore, but there will still almost certainly be text you'd want to avoid. Religious or not, I'd lose respect for an observant Jew who'd take part in singing "Joy to the world, the Lord is come" or "O come, let us adore him" or even "We wish you a Merry Christmas". At this point I don't think there's anything even remotely religious about Santa Claus though.

Calling it an Xmas party specifically could have halachic implications regarding one's ability/permissibility to attend according to the Rav I asked.
